# Can't run digikam on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, 23.10, digikam

I initially installed Digikam through the terminal. Whenever I run it, it launches the initial welcome screen and options, but then when I go through those steps the app just crashes. If I launch it from the terminal I get this:

```
digikam
Gtk-Message: 16:11:11.941: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
digikam.metaengine: ExifTool process cannot be started ( "" )
digikam.facedb: Cannot found faces engine model "shapepredictor.dat"
digikam.facedb: Faces recognition feature cannot be used!
digikam.facedb: Cannot found faces engine DNN model "openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7"
digikam.facedb: Faces recognition feature cannot be used!
WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
QGLXContext: Failed to create dummy context
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:1001:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Hspell: can't open /usr/share/hspell/hebrew.wgz.sizes.
kf.sonnet.clients.hspell: HSpellDict::HSpellDict: Init failed
kf.xmlgui: Unhandled container to remove :  Digikam::DigikamApp
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DefaultSwapBehavior, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I then tried the appimage, and if I run that I get this:

```
./digiKam-8.2.0-x86-64.appimage
-- digiKam Linux AppImage Bundle
-- Use 'help' as CLI argument to know all available options for digiKam application.
-- Notes: to integrate this bundle to your desktop, use AppImageLauncher.
--        to enable all debug messages on the console, use 'export QT_LOGGING_RULES="digikam*=true"'.
--        to extract the bundle contents locally, use option '--appimage-extract' on the command line.
-- Detected host Linux ubuntu-64-23.10
-- AppImage mounted directory: /tmp/.mount_digiKa1r1qyr
Check library libudev.so.0
Check library libxcb-dri3.so.0
Check library libcrypto.so.1.1
Check library libssl.so.1.1
Check library libnss3.so
Check library libnssutil3.so
Check library libsmime3.so
Check library libgmodule-2.0.so.0
Check library libgnutls.so.30
-- Preloading shared libs: :/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

Thank you very much to anyone who can shed any light on this.

Comment: The "kf.xmlgui" line and above are normal in my working install. You can try updating the system, switching to the HWE kernel, and adding the kisak-mesa PPA for the OpenGL driver. If not, you can disable the GPU with `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 digikam`